# Java SWT file saving

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I've a problem with file saving, as I've searched I wrote it well all worked except one thing, the file not really created. what are missing?

```
        Button btnExport = new Button(composite_1, SWT.NONE);
    btnExport.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            FileDialog fileSave = new FileDialog(pmComp, SWT.SAVE);
            fileSave.setFilterNames(new String[] {"CSV"});
            fileSave.setFilterExtensions(new String[] {"*.csv"});
            fileSave.setFilterPath("c:\\"); // Windows path
            fileSave.setFileName("your_file_name.csv");
            fileSave.open();

            System.out.println("File Saved as: " + fileSave.getFileName());
        }
    });
    btnExport.setBounds(246, 56, 75, 40);
    btnExport.setText("Export");
```

Comment: The `FileDialog` doesn't create files, it is used to enable the user to select a folder and a filename. Once that is done, you need to create the file and write to it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FileDialog](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FFileDialog.html) :

> Instances of this class allow the user to navigate the file system and
>   **select or enter a file name**.

The dialog won't create the file by itself, you have to retrieve the chosen file name, then create the file.

e.g

```
String name = fileSave.getFileName();
File file = new File(name);
file.createNewFile();
```

Comment: I can't understand this line: `(new File(name)).createNewFile();`

Comment: it's told me use try/catch, do you know why?

Comment: Yes, because when dealing with file access, many methods can throw `IOException` (`createNewFile()` in this case) , and you have to catch those exceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much! its worked. and i mixed something with the other comment here :)

Answer (score 1):

`FileDialog` is just used to select the location for the file save. It does **not** actually create or write the file - you have to do that.

So

```
String savePath = fileSave.open();

// TODO your code to write the file to savePath
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Button btnExport = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
        btnExport.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                FileDialog fileSave = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.SAVE);
                fileSave.setFilterNames(new String[] { "CSV" });
                fileSave.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.csv" });
                fileSave.setFilterPath("C:\\"); // Windows path
                fileSave.setFileName("your_file_name.csv");
                String open = fileSave.open();
                File file = new File(open);
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("File Saved as: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        btnExport.setBounds(246, 56, 75, 40);
        btnExport.setText("Export");

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }

    }
}
```